# How to make a Button containing an Icon and a title that ends in ellipsis in React Native?

Tags: react-native, button, icons, ellipsis

As the title says, I try to make a Button element in React Native, that would contain an Icon on the left side and a title on the right side. If the title is too long, it should end in ellipsis. This is the code I tried:

```
import { Icon, Button } from 'react-native-elements'

<Button
    buttonStyle={bStyle}
    icon={icon}
    title={title}
    titleProps={{
        numberOfLines: 1
    }}
    onPress={() => onPress()}
/>
```

Also, bStyle uses justifyContent: 'flex-start'. The result is that the title does end in ellipsis but it seems to determine its own size before taking the Icon into account, resulting the tail of the title to not fitting to the button, but rather going too far right. If I delete the icon, it works correctly. Any idea on how to fix?